# SQL Database Backup using Java

Tags: java, sql

I have tried several ways of getting this code to work and to back up one of my databases from MAMP but the closest I got was it updating an empty sql file but not printing anything inside it.

Please could someone help me. Thank you

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at guidesign.LoginPage.btn_loginActionPerformed(LoginPage.java:175)
    at guidesign.LoginPage.access$000(LoginPage.java:16)
    at guidesign.LoginPage$1.actionPerformed(LoginPage.java:73)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)








        try {
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process p = runtime.exec("C:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump -u root -p pass db > C:/Desktop/Backup.sql");

            int processComplete = p.waitFor();

            if (processComplete == 0) {

                System.out.println("Backup created successfully!");

            } else {
                backupMsg.setText("Could not create the backup");
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? Does the process complete successfully or not? You have to give more details before somebody could answer.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Sorry, it said I get a null pointer exception and the process does not complete

Comment: It would be more useful if you post your complete stacktrace as a part of the answer. The stacktrace is the thing that can point you to the exact line of code that is causing the exception.

Comment: The exception is happening in your `btn_loginActionPerformed()` method on line 175. Since the source code for this is missing, I can't really tell what's wrong, but you should start your search there.

Comment: That button is used to login in (which works) to the admin page, the backup button (with this code) is in the admin page.